# Change a part of a UI text element's color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, if I have a game object in my canvas and I want to change one word's color at runtime, or simply insert a color into the string that displays, how would I do that?
C# and unity, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Rich Text](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html) to change the color of specific words.

Just add the following line: `<color=yellow>Hello,</color> World!` to your 'UIText' component in Inspector. This will change the color of the word inside the tags regardless of the color set in 'UIText' component.

Comment: Oh, excellent, that works? I knew about that but I thought they changed it in the new version or something. I'll try it when I get home, thanks!

Comment: Uh... it does work, but it won't in my particular situation. Lookit:  http://orig10.deviantart.net/0b5c/f/2016/157/a/4/animation_by_gmr516-da59eb1.gif

Comment: Try pasting this whole code first <color=yellow>t</color>, then keep adding the remaining letters one by one inside your tags.

Comment: I figured out a weird way to do it. I wrapped the string like so: dialogueBoxText.text = "<color=red>" + dialoguestring + "</color>";

Comment: What if I want to lerp (rapidly change) color elegantly, but only for 1 word or letter? This doesn't work for that