# How can I change only a single letter's color in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a card game and I want to display a text which is a description of a card. Say, "Deal 4 damages to the target." and I want this "4" part to be colored differently. How can I do this?

```
public string formerPartOfText = "Deal ";
public int damage = 4;
public string rearerPartOfText = " damages to the target.";

public string finalText = formerPartOfText + damage.ToString + rearerPartOfText;

print(finalText);
```

I divided the string to two parts, because I wanted the variable damage to be able to be changed

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change a part of a UI text element's color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646222/change-a-part-of-a-ui-text-elements-color)

Answer (score 7):

[Rich Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html)

And specifically the color tag:

```
var damage = 4;
var str = $"Deal <color=#ff0000ff>{ damage }</color> damage to the target";
```

Comment: Maybe you should also explain [`$` stringinterpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to a newby ;)

Comment: @derHugo you may wish to edit your comment to direct the user to the English page.

Comment: yes but I can't ^^ [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) should have been the link